# Audio Input not working on 13-inch Macbook Pro Mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio

I am trying to connect an audio device (analog synthesizer) to the input of my 13-inch Mid-2012 Macbook Pro running OS X Mavericks 10.9.3. The synthesizer's output is a standard 1/8th inch stereo plug. According to http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3625, I should be able to switch this from System Preferences. However, my screen looks like this even when my device is plugged in:

[image: Screenshot]

There is no option to use the audio jack as an input.

How do I connect my device to the audio input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [technical specification](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp649):

```
Audio

Stereo speakers with subwoofer
Omnidirectional microphone
Headphone port
Support for Apple iPhone headset with remote and microphone
Support for audio line out (digital/analog)
```

There is no direct "microphone in" or "line in" connector. The only way to connect a microphone is to use a splitter meant for iPhone and similar devices, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006T65CXE). You should note that the input is mono only, no stereo support.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the first sentence:

> Plug the input audio device into the combination audio port using the
>   **proper adapter cable**.

You can not use your "standard" stereo plug, use Apple specific plug.